# Can an employee serve longer notice period in exchange for paying back a joining bonus?

Tags: resignation, notice-period, bonus

About 2 months ago, I started a new job. My employment contract states that there will be 3 months probation, 1 month notice period and if I resign within the first 12 months of my job, I would need to pay back the joining bonus.

3 days into the new job, I found that the job was not what I signed up for. What I was assigned to at work differs from my job description. I am based full time at a client's place and I have spoken to the client line manager. He asked me to speak to my company's account manager. I did, and the account manager told me he will speak to the client line manager and requested me to "stick with it" for now. No clear indication on how long the situation will last.

As of now I am contemplating to resign. But at the same time I do not want to pay back the joining bonus. Can I negotiate serving a longer notice period in exchange of paying back the joining bonus? What other options do I have?

Comment: Your question depends heavily on the company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies. Vote to close. My advice: Learn the lesson. Be careful when you sign a contract. Short answer to your question. All business are for money. They'll agree to whatever if they don't lose money. And help them to make money will be even better.

Answer (score 4):

You can always attempt to negotiate, but a negotiation is two sided and both parties have to agree. This means that you should be thinking about what your employer will get out of this.

Your current negotiating position seems to be *"I would like to breach my contractual terms and I would like you to pay me extra money, you will get a dissatisfied employee for a longer period of time."* That doesn't sound very attractive for your company.

3 days is no time at all. If the job isn't what you signed up to do then you should be asking your line manager for concrete plans to get you doing what you were hired for. Or, if you wish, just quitting. Don't be surprised if they don't let you keep the joining bonus though.